# Access SQL - if/then in update query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table "SPPB" with fields:

Total
Status

I need to update the Status field to either 1 or -9 depending on the value in the Total field. I.e., if Total is null, then Status is -9. If Total is not null, then Status is 1.

I'm having trouble with syntax in Access...

Comment: you need to use an IIF statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options.  The first is a single statement:

```
update sppb
    set status = iif(total is null, -9, 1);
```

Or, two statements:

```
update sppb
    set status = -9
    where total is null;

update sppb
    set status = 1
    where total is not null;
```

In this case, the single statement version is probably better, in terms of performance.