# How to update the value of a cell (e.g. cell D112) in access based on a comparison of the value of B112 to the values of all the cells above B112?

Tags: if-statement, ms-access, iif

I'm trying to find a way to detect and label duplicate companies in a table. Say the company name is in column B. When ACME company is entered for the second (up to infinity) time in the table, I want an automated way that makes the table return "Duplicate" in column D in the row where ACME is entered for the second, third, fourth (up to infinity) time, without changing anything in the row where ACME was entered for the first time. Is there a way to do this in MS Access?

Thanks!

Comment: Cells? It sounds like you are looking for Excel to do this.

Comment: So why are you saving company name into this table and not just company ID? Why don't you just sort records by company - duplicates should be obvious.

Comment: in short access has a wizard for finding duplicates under query wizard.  break the job into parts to start.  run the duplicate wizard to get that query run a separate update query.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66567663/how-do-i-mark-duplicate-values-from-one-field-in-another-field  comment if you need a translation

Comment: Thanks @mazoula, that worked like a charm! Is it possible to change this code to allow for changing the values of non-duplicates to "Non-duplicates" as well?

Comment: yes, one simple way that fits in a comment would be to run a second update query (use the query designer) and replace null in the Duplicate column with "Non-duplicate" assuming you have already marked all duplicates using a first query and there are no other issues

Comment: to do it all at once the following should work though I haven't tried it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724332/access-sql-if-then-in-update-query